# How to store List<Object> in Flutter using sharedPreferences?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-sharedpreference

I want to save list of PlatformFile, with the help of file_picker library and store them using sharedpreferences and then load them back. list -> List

Comment: Voting to close as your question is so broad and vague it's unanswerable. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. You can convert that list of PlatformFile into json string and store that string ti shared preferences. It's the best way to store it.Otherwise you need to store them in local db. And when you read just convert that string to list of PlatformFiles again.